# Regex to match digit values separated by space, but whole string doesn't end with space

Tags: java, regex, android-edittext

I implement an `EditText` that allows to input prices separated by a space.
The prices can be both integer and decimal values.

For example:

> 3900 156.2 140.38 200 10

So, I've found the following regex:

`(\d+([.]\d{1,2})? )+`

But it works only with a space at the end. (I know it's absolutely expectable)

Is it possible to make this regex to ignore a space at the end of input string?

Or maybe you can suggest smth else?

Thanks.

Comment: Just remove the space in your regex? `(\d+([.]\d{1,2})?)+`

Comment: @karthikmanchala to be more precice, the space after the `?` mark and before the `)` ... :)

Comment: You should mark one of the answers correct if it solved your problem.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I've chosen Rafael's one, because it goes exactly as I expected. And I upvoted yours, because you provided very flexible regex with such a good explanation which helps me to convert your regex to what I need. Hope I was right.

Comment: @Ivan I don't know... _were_ you right? ;-P

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I meant if I was right in choosing the correct answer. As for me, they are both correct. As for the regex to which I convert yours: ``^\d+(.\d+)?(\s\d+(.\d+)?)*$``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use (almost) the same pattern you provided:

```
(\d+([.]\d{1,2})? )*(\d+([.]\d{1,2})?)
```

This is less flexible than Tim's answer (like: if you put more than one space between numbers it will fail, etc) but it might be useful anyway.

Comment: A single space between numbers is exactly what I want. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest the following pattern:

```
^\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:\s+\d+(?:\.\d+)?)*$
```

In plain English, this says to match a (possibly) decimal number, followed by one or more whitespace characters, and another (possibly) decimal number, that happening zero or more times.

Have a look at the demo link below.

### Demo

But since you're using Java, I can suggest an alternative here.  Since you will likely have to access each number, you could instead split the string coming from the `EditText` by space, and then check each "number" to make sure it really is a number.  Something like this:

```
String input = "3900 156.2 140.38 200 10";
String[] nums = input.split("\\s+");
for (String num : nums) {
    if (num.matches("\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?")) {
        // then process this as a number
    }
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. Actually I want to validate an EditText. So I want to allow a user to input prices separated by single whitespace character. I just disable save button unless the user's input matches the regex. I've already convert your regex to what I need. I've just replaced one character :) Thank you very much